# prevent Logging duplication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have many apps around the world that sends data to my server.
all data are produced using Kafka stream as avro into Kafka topic with 40 partitions
I would like to prevent duplication data.
in my case, the apps can send the same message many times (even after a few minutes ), and I would like to know if Kafka can help me to prevent it.
Is there any option to "Hash" the message and prevent produced twice to Kafka?

I have read about exactly once etc.. it seems like it supports the case the producer failed to produce.

I would like that Kafka will prevent duplicated message for limitted time (let's say 10 min )

Comment: I think, this is an event de-duplication use case. Cf. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Answer (score 0):

If the producer of the data is a Streams app, you could look into using the Suppress operator to buffer and suppress duplicates.

See:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#controlling-emit-rate

This assumes that the duplicates are coming from KTable updates.

If you want to provide an example of one of these upstream apps, I can give a more concrete example, but it basically looks like:

```
myKTable
  .suppress(untilTimeLimit(
    ofMinutes(10), 
    maxBytes(1_000_000).emitEarlyWhenFull()
  ))
  .to(...the output topic...)
```

If you want to *prevent* the duplicates, you have to do something like this on the producer side. On the other hand, if you just want to save on *storing* the duplicates, you can configure log compaction on the topics in question.

I hope this helps!

-John

Comment: I think, this is an event de-duplication use case. Cf. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples